# Oracle SQL Month to percent % complete Formula

Tags: sql, oracle, formula

Hi I am pretty new to Oracle.  I want to calculate the percent of the month complete.  I know it would be the current day divided by the last day of the month but I am not sure how to write that out in SQL in Oracle

So for today it would be the 21/30 since its the 21st of September and there are 30 days in the month.  The percent of month complete would be 70% and that is what I am wanting to get in oracle

Comment: Please include your table(s) structure along with sample data and the desired output.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Percent complete, until what time of today? Your computation (21/30) is until midnight at the END of today, is that what you need? Even when the time is midnight at the BEGINNING of today (end of YESTERDAY)?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    SELECT ( extract( day from SYSDATE )/ 
             extract( day from LAST_DAY(SYSDATE) ))* 100 
    FROM dual;
```

[Here is a good overview](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/the-most-useful-date-and-time-functions-in-oracle-database)

Comment: Note my Comment to the OP though. If SYSDATE is 21 Sept 2017 at 00:00 in 24 hour notation, the computation will return 21/30. That is a bit weird, because at that time exactly 20 days had passes, not 21.

Comment: So we can trunc(sysdate)

Comment: need to add rounding to the calculation formula  `SELECT  round( ( extract( day from SYSDATE+1 )/ 
             extract( day from LAST_DAY(SYSDATE) ))* 100 )
    FROM dual;`